# Unrecognized Selector [MKPointAnnotation index]

Tags: ios, dictionary, annotations, selector

I am trying to add an annotation by touch onto a mapview and after I release the press I get this error:

> [MKPointAnnotation index] : unrecognized selector sent to instance

Can anyone give me an idea of what the cause is?

Code:

```
- (void)handleLongPress:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    if (gestureRecognizer.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        return;
    }
    CGPoint touchPoint = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.mapView];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D touchMapCoordinate = [self.mapView convertPoint:touchPoint toCoordinateFromView:self.mapView];
    MKPointAnnotation *point = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    point.coordinate = touchMapCoordinate;
    point.title = @"Test";
    point.subtitle = @"Test2";
    for (id annotation in self.mapView.annotations) {
        [self.mapView removeAnnotation:annotation];
    }

    [self.mapView addAnnotation:point];
}
```

Here is what I have in my **ViewDidLoad** method:

```
if (_isSelectLocation)
{
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressGestureRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
    longPressGestureRecognizer.minimumPressDuration = 0.5;
    [self.mapView addGestureRecognizer:longPressGestureRecognizer];
}
```

Added Stack trace:

```
Stack trace : (
0   Lookcounter                         0x0000000100145680 -[MapViewController handleLongPress:] + 1016
1   UIKit                               0x000000018a2ceec4 <redacted> + 276
2   UIKit                               0x000000018a168508 <redacted> + 580
3   UIKit                               0x000000018a5d9214 <redacted> + 60
4   UIKit                               0x000000018a12c26c <redacted> + 292
5   UIKit                               0x000000018a12a618 <redacted> + 2504
6   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000185673ff0 <redacted> + 32
7   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000185670f7c <redacted> + 360
8   CoreFoundation                      0x000000018567135c <redacted> + 836
9   CoreFoundation                      0x000000018559cf74 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 396
10  GraphicsServices                    0x000000018eff76fc GSEventRunModal + 168
11  UIKit                               0x000000018a19ed94 UIApplicationMain + 1488
12  Lookcounter                         0x00000001001418d0 main + 124
13  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000197a32a08 <redacted> + 4
)
```

Comment: Is there a place in your code where you send a `index` message to an object? The code you posted looks fine. Can you also post a whole stack trace?

Comment: I edited my post to show it. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Yep, though the redacted parts are strange and uninformative. Could you add an exception breakpoint (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html) or debug your handler step by step and tell us on which line does it fail precisely? Does it happen always, or with the second/third/etc touch? Also on which device (and if simulator) and iOS version are you getting these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what is the problem. I have copied all your code, and works well. And I post it as a project in github.

https://github.com/zhangjianxing/trySelectorApp

I believe there is other thing cause compiler did not recognized selector (in swift if you set "handleLongPress" to be private, the same error will arise ).

I suggest you comment other method/properties, and try again.

Comment: It ended up being something in one of the delegate methods. Specifically the viewForAnnotation.

Comment: its pretty good that you find it out. But why "viewForAnnotation" will cause "handleLongPress" unrecognized. Is there some private function, which has the same name, in the delegate?

Comment: I was using a custom annotation for other purposes in the app and it has a property that the generic annotation doesn't.